# Having some trouble with php array algorithm

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I'm not good at algorithm. Here is my trouble.

I have an array:

```
$test_arr = array(
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
  4 => 'e',
  5 => 'f',
  6 => 'g',
  7 => 'h',
  8 => 'i',
);
```

How do i reorder it with some algorithms like this:

```
$test_arr = array(
  0 => array(
    'a', 'b',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'c', 'd',
  ),
  2 => array(
    'e', 'f'
  ),
  3 => array(
    'g', 'h',
  ),
  4 => array(
    'i',
  ),
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google: `PHP array_chunk()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP already has a builtin function to do exactly the same task. That is `array_chunk()`

Try this:

```
<?php
$test_arr = array(
0 => 'a',
1 => 'b',
2 => 'c',
3 => 'd',
4 => 'e',
5 => 'f',
6 => 'g',
7 => 'h',
8 => 'i',
);
var_dump(array_chunk($test_arr, 2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is algorithm you are looking for:

```
$test_arr = array(
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
  4 => 'e',
  5 => 'f',
  6 => 'g',
  7 => 'h',
  8 => 'i',
);

$tmp_array = [];
$new_array = [];
$i = 1;
foreach($test_arr as $k => $v){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $tmp_array[] = $v;
        $new_array[] = $tmp_array;
        $tmp_array = [];
    }else{
        $tmp_array[] = $v;
    }

    $i++;
}
if(count($tmp_array) > 0){
    $new_array[] = $tmp_array;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This solution loops through the given array and saves current and next values to a new array ONLY if the current key is either 0 or an even number.

```
<?php
$test_arr = array(
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
  4 => 'e',
  5 => 'f',
  6 => 'g',
  7 => 'h',
  8 => 'i',
);
$newarray = array();
foreach( $test_arr as $key => $value){
    if ( ($key == 0) || (($key % 2) == 0)){ 
        if( isset($test_arr[($key + 1)]) ) { $next = $test_arr[($key + 1)]; } else { $next = ''; }
        $newarray[] = array($value,  $next);
    }
}
echo print_r($newarray, true);
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => f
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => g
            [1] => h
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => i
            [1] => 
        )

)
```